# WordPress, all menu item (pages) turn into empty "custom links" after 17/18 items

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, phpmyadmin, ini

I have a strange problem. 
After I Add more than 17/18 pages to a menu, It breaks after I save it.
Upon saving, all the items turn into empty "custom links." Note: the sub-menus also become level 1 as well as becoming empty custom links.

All the issues I search for, do not match my problem. The closest thing is a "menu item limit" with a php.ini or .user.ini fix.

I've tried the .user.ini fix and it didn't solve this. 
I've tried deactivating all plugins. 
I've tried switching themes. 
I manually updated the core files.

What could be causing this?

Comment: I found a temporary solution. if I click "manage with live preview" I can see the menu correctly inside the theme customization. and it actually displays in the front end when I save it. However, this is a client, and I can't just leave the site functionality broken.

Comment: The fix you've stumbled on is correct. It's a server limit. You need to adjust the configuration in order to resolve

Comment: @NathanDawson why does this server limit not effect the menu when changing it inside of theme customization?

Answer (score 0):

increase MAX INPUT VARIABLES to 10000

php_value max_input_vars 10000

via htaccess or php.ini configuration

Comment: You should at least include the exact ini settings that needs to be set or exact code to add in `.htaccess`.